# Angularjs 1.6 show/hide section when click on menu items

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie in AngularJS. I have navbar with nav-items like this:

```
<div class="header-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="nav-area">
                    <nav class="mainmenu">
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">  
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!/link2">Link 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!/link3">Link 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!/link4">Link 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!/link5">Link 5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!/link6">Link 6</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and section:

```
<section class="hero-area">
//some text
</section>
```

how can I show section when I click on Link 1, and hide when click on rest of links. Default active link is "Link1" so I need to show section when page start.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Create a toggle functionality using ng-if or ng-show

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a ng-click + ng-show (or ng-hide)?

```
<div class="header-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="nav-area">
                    <nav class="mainmenu">
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">  
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="#" data-ng-click="showSection = 1">Link 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!/link2" data-ng-click="showSection = 2">Link 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!/link3" data-ng-click="showSection = 3">Link 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!/link4" data-ng-click="showSection = 4">Link 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!/link5" data-ng-click="showSection = 5">Link 5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!/link6" data-ng-click="showSection = 6">Link 6</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>


<section class="hero-area" data-ng-init="showSection = 1" data-ng-show="showSection === 1">
//some text
</section>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, because I want to show the section at the start website.

Comment: In theory, you should establish a base value inside your controller (assuming AnuglarJS 1.x). You could also use data-ng-init="showSection = 1" somewhere in the view though as well (not sure if it's considered 'best practice' or not though, and I welcome any other's to comment). Will revise answer with an ng-init added..

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/) which has a solution for this problem and much more. It will also allow you to restore the active page (and other parameters) from bookmarks.

If you prefer quick&dirty you could try a scope variable:

`<a ng-click="active_section='link 2'">Link 2</a>
...
<section ng-show="active_section==='link 2'">`